# Why bounty not awarded to any answer even after expiration?

Tags: discussion, bounty

For the below question,

[Download HTML files locally in Hybrid app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617593/download-html-files-locally-in-hybrid-app/27723440#27723440)

There was an open bounty of 50 which ended now recently. But i do not see that awarded to any answer.

I like to understand the reason. As far as i understand, bounty once created should be rewarded to one of the eligible answers within the time period. Please correct me if i am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: at the expiration, if there is an answer with two upvotes at least, half the bounty is awarded. None of these answers have 2 upvotes or more

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The user who started the bounty never came back and awarded it. The system also didn't auto-award half the bounty because there were no answers scored 2 or higher. So, the bounty disappeared when the time expired.

There is no requirement that a bounty *must* be awarded.

Comment: How does the system "auto" award the bounty if there are multiple answers with score >2? Is it selected randomly or based on date of post?

Comment: @Pacerier It picks the highest scored answer that was posted first, within the bounty period.

Comment: Odd, thought it was random selection among the answers with equal scores.